# programmatically excel cells to be auto fit width & height

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

when i convert datatable to .csv my excel sheets are generated as below:
[image]

and tried like below:

```
sw.Write(string.Format("=\"{0}\"", drow[i].ToString()));
```

then my excel sheets were like:

[image]

note that cells have =" " characters;

i'm trying to do like auto fit width & height of each cells programmatically. How?

Comment: Have you tried `Excel.Rows.AutoFit` and `Excel.Columns.AutoFit`?

Comment: Are you just creating a .csv file or are you using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to create an actual excel file?

Comment: @paul as of now i'm just creating the xl by stream; Is i need to load that xl in interop? thanks for your reply....

Comment: @Terry pls find my comment above...

Comment: @Shankar yes - my suggestion would only work with interop.

Comment: @paul thank you. lemme chk this...

Answer (score 18):

Try getting the range and then do Autofit

```
Range.Rows.AutoFit();
Range.Columns.AutoFit();
```

Answer (score 2):

This questions just helped me to solve part of a problem.
I had to copy the data to a secondary, auxiliary sheet, then send it to the datagrid, but when I did, it would display in the datagrid the sequence of ######### for some of my data that was larger than the field itself.
So I used 
`**sheets.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit();**`
 to solve the problem every time a new column is created.
Where **sheets** is my variable who received the `**Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet**`.

Thank you guys very much.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on another page:

C#

http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.3.0/SpreadsheetGear~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~AutoFit.html

// Automatically set the width on columns B and C. 
worksheet.Cells["B:C"].Columns.AutoFit();

// Set the row height to automatic on rows 7 through 9. 
worksheet.Cells["7:9"].Rows.AutoFit();

Comment: That ("xlWorkSheet.Cells["1:10"].Rows.AutoFit();") thows an err for me, more specifically "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled"