# C# - Interop Excel fit size cells

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel-interop

I'm developing a Windows Form Application with C#, and I have already implemented Interop for Excel on it to create a worksheet with some data.

I can already create the excel document but when I open it, the size of the cells look like this:

[image]

I have already implemented some functions on the code to try to fix this problem:

```
char[] NosCharsToRemove = "\n".ToCharArray();
ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[row, col] = norm.comments.TrimStart(NosCharsToRemove);
```

Or,

```
ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[row, col] = norm.comments.TrimStart();
```

Or,

```
ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[row, col] = norm.comments.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
```

But no one has worked.

If I go to the Excel document and I tap double click in one of the "ugly" cells, and then, I focus another random cell, the "ugly cell" is fixed "magically".

[image]

Does anyone know how can I fix this problem programatically?

I will appreciate so much their help!

Comment: Try ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[row, col].Resize.RowHeight = X or... xlWorkSheet.Rows.RowHeight = X;

Comment: Have you tried the autofit? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711163/programmatically-excel-cells-to-be-auto-fit-width-height

Comment: @NuWin your answer have helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try wordwrap style for the cell. Refer [msdn wordwrap for range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821514.aspx)

```
ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Alignment.WrapText = true;
```